# ARM template - Mapping application insights/app-service-plan of a different resource group

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create 3 resource groups using ARM template

1. rg-prod-remserv-digital-onlinesetup-shared
2. rg-prod-remserv-digital-onlinesetup-gov
3. rg-prod-remserv-digital-onlinesetup-non-gov

Creating the following resources in each of the respective resource groups,

1. rg-prod-remserv-digital-onlinesetup-shared

   - An app-service plan, asp-prod-remserv-digital-onlinesetup-shared
   - An application insights resource, ai-prod-remserv-digital-onlinesetup-shared
2. rg-prod-remserv-digital-onlinesetup-gov

   - An app-service, which uses the app-service plan and application-insights resource from the shared resource group (i.e rg-prod-remserv-digital-onlinesetup-shared)
3. rg-prod-remserv-digital-onlinesetup-non-gov

   - An app-service, which uses the app-service plan and application-insights resource from the shared resource group (i.e rg-prod-remserv-digital-onlinesetup-shared)

Please advice, How do i create a dependency so that all these are created once while executing my ARM template.

The code is available in the following path,

```
https://github.com/Manjunath-Jayaram/ARM-MultipleResourceGroups
```

Comment: Assuming, the app-services and the app-service-plan are in the same region, it is possible. You can have a look at nested template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates#nested-template

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for replying. My app-service and app-service-plan are sitting under different resource groups.

Comment: Yes but are resource groups are in the same region/datacenter ? I think it is the only restriction which make sense

Comment: Yes, they are part of the same region.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for sharing the article. Could you please let me know, how will i be able to link the templates which are present in the same solution, rather than linking them from a storage account.

Comment: So have a look at nested template, it should not be that complicated. Let me know if you get some problems with it

Comment: You can use nested template which mean every thing is defined in the same json file

Comment: Hi Aryan, have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a fully nested template where everything will be deployed in one go or here's another way below

---

First in the outputs section of the shared template you need to pass names of the  appServicePlan and the ApplicationInsights.

```
"outputs": {
     "appServicePlan ": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "[parameters('asp-prod-digital-onlinesetup-sharedName')]"
        },
     "applicationInsights":{
     "type":"string",
     "value":"your app insights name"
       }
  }
```

So in the `rg-prod-remserv-digital-onlinesetup-gov` and `rg-prod-remserv-digital-onlinesetup-non-gov` templates under the resources array, use the  `"dependsOn": [ ]` parameter to pass the values of app-service plan and application-insights resource from the shared resource group.

```
"dependsOn": [
    "[variables('sharedAppServicePlan')]",
    "[variables('sharedApplicationInsights')]",
    "storageLoop",
  ],
```

After deployment get the values of the outputs  from shared template and pass it on. It can be done by `"[reference('<name-of-deployment>').outputs.<property-name>.value]"`

Read full [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates#get-values-from-linked-template)

Hope it helped. :-)